# Sum the nth value for every key in a python dictionary

Tags: python

***EDIT***

I have the following dictionary:

```
dictionary = {'abc': [20, 'john'], 'def': [25, 'jim'], 'ghi': [30, 'jack']}
```

I would like to sum all of the first values for each key and define it as a variable

Expected answer:

```
20 + 25 + 30

total_score = 75
```

Comment: This looks suspicuiously like a class assignment... So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: There are no first values, as your outer dictionary contains *sets*, which are unordered.

Comment: As usual, we have to ask you: where exactly did you get stuck with solving this? Is there some error you ran into? Are your sets always consisting of just an integer value and a string, or will there be fewer or more values sometimes?

Comment: The first value will always be a number. Should i be doing this a different way?

Comment: What you have shown as example is the same as if you had written `{'abc': {'john', 20}, ...}` – what should happen now?

Comment: `{'abc': [20, 'john'], 'def': [25, 'jim'], 'ghi': [30, 'jack']}` like this yes?

Comment: Now you have a different question. Or do you mean that what you have shown before is not what you actually have?

Comment: I made a mistake and didnt create a dictionary. sorry. original question has been fixed up

Comment: @SOK: now you have a very trivial question. Read the Python tutorial [section on generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions), loop over `dictionary.values()`, index each entry with `[0]` and then use the `sum()` function.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. Apologies for the mix up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `dict()` having `set()` assigned to each key. You can not index sets. So considering that the first value in the set will always be the value you want is meaningless.

A workaround is to use list comprehension to build a `list()` from the `set()`, that list containing only integer elements. Since you only have one integer per set, then the first index of the list will be the value of interest.

```
dct = {'abc': {20, 'john'}, 'def': {25, 'jim'}, 'ghi': {30, 'jack'}}

var = 0

for v in dct.values():
    v = [x for x in v if isinstance(x, int)][0]
    var += v
    
print(var)
```

Output:

```
75
```

**Edit:**

Since the OP edited his question, the new code would be:

```
dct = {'abc': [20, 'john'], 'def': [25, 'jim'], 'ghi': [30, 'jack']}

var = 0

for v in dct.values():
    var += v[0]
    
print(var)
```

Or:

```
var = sum(v[0] for v in dct.values())
```

Comment: Thanks alot! sorry for the mix up with my question but this answer (bottom one) is perfect

Comment: or just use `var = sum(lst[0] for lst in dict.values())`.